# How to set all scales of an object to some value?

Tags: transforms

I know I can use the scale tool or edit an object s X, Y and Z scales in the transform window but how can I do something like "Set all scales of an object (X, Y and Z) to 2.5" for example?

Set them all to an exact value all at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> while click-dragging over all desired scale property values, release the <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> then type in the desired value.
[image]